# Nvidia Decoder Performance numbers

Tags: video, nvidia, decoder, nvenc

What is the maximum FPS from a NVIDIA GPU for a 720p video?
NVIDIA has published figures for 1080p only.

From GTC 2016, http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6226-abhijit-patait-high-performance-video.pdf, can someone explain the TESLA PERFORMANCE numbers for transcoding. What is (14+14) for Tesla M6.
If one NVENC is 7, then 2 should be 7+7. Right??

Comment: Your question seems to be misleading. I think it should be "NVidia transcoding performance numbers", since both the NVDEC and NVENC are being put into play?

Comment: No it is not. When you are comparing video performance of the hardware, one would be interested in knowing transcoding, decoding and encoding numbers. Though I have encoding numbers what NVIDIA pulished for its hardware, I am not able to find official decoder(only 1080p available) and transcoder numbers.

Comment: I see. Sorry I can't help you; but I'd suggest rephrasing your question a bit to make this clearer.